# Is the Integral Operator $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)\ni\varphi\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi (x) g(x) dx, g\in L_{p'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (Frechet-) Smooth?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, frechet-derivative

I don't know much about Frechet-differentiability. I just need to know if the following statement is true.

Let $p^{-1}+p'^{-1}=1$. Let $g\in L_{p'}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$. Then the operator

$ G: L_p(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}, \varphi\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x)g(x)dx$

is infinitely many times Frechet differentiable.

Any literature regarding problems like these are helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It is a bounded (by Holder) linear transformation. So...

Comment: Due to linearity (G(x+h)=G(x)+G(h)) the Frechet derivative of G is the bounded map G itself. So, G is infinitely many times Frechet differentiable.